# Not getting clusters formed in 3D for 38dimensions

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Basically I am using K-means for dataset for 527*38(rows x columns).
I want to use K-means and I have set 3 clusters but I am not able to visualize it in 3D-dimensions. If anyone can help i have tried it i will show it

I have converted my dataset x4 to list

Following is the code

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
# Number of clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
# Fitting the input data
kmeans = kmeans.fit(x4)
# Centroid values
c = kmeans.cluster_centers_
import numpy as np
x4=np.array(x4)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x4[:, 0], x4[:, 1], x4[:, 2])
ax.scatter(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], marker='*', c='#050505', s=1000)
```

Trying to plot in 3d 
i have attached image of output i am getting
[image: mycode]

Here is the expected output image. Something like this is what i need for 3 clusters
[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to plot data points with 38 dimensions in a 3D plot using only the first three dimensions, which is incorrect.

To properly visualize the clusters, you can try the following.

1. Consider top 3 dimensions with most variance for plotting.
2. Use dimension reduction methods like [Principle Component Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) to reduce 38 dimensions to 3 dimensions.

Comment: I know that by reducing dimensions through PCA we would able to see it but without implementing PCA & directly I want to implement Kmeans and see for my dataset whether clusters are formed or not Is it possible that way to visualize it ? or do we need to implement pca then only we would able to visualize it?

Comment: Ideally, you should use PCA to reduce dimensions. However, you can try to plot the top 3 Dimensions with most variation to visualize your clusters, however it may not work that well.

Comment: You can cluster in all 38 dimensions and use 2 or 3 dimensions just fort plotting. PCA then it's the most appropriate choice, because the first dimensions have most of the variance.

Comment: But I would recommend to only use the *rotation* from PCA, not the scaling!